# SQLAlchemy Constraint on field with multiple joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm using SQL Alchemy to instantiate a database. I have 4 tables in it:

- `table_A` with `id` and `b_id` columns
- `table_B` with `id` column
- `table_C` with `id` and `b_id` columns
- `table_D` with `id`, `c_id` and `a_id` columns
- There is a one-to-many relationship between `table_B.id` and `table_A.b_id`
- There is a one-to-many relationship between `table_B.id` and `table_C.b_id`
- There is a one-to-many relationship between `table_C.id` and `table_D.c_id`

There is a 'special' relationship between `table_A.id` and `table_D.a_id` :

I want the relationship chain to apply to it. I'm looking for some kind of validator that only allows commiting if `table_D.a_id` is included in the result of the following SQL request :

```
SELECT table_A.id 
FROM table_A 
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.b_id == table_B.id 
INNER JOIN table_C ON table_C.b_id == table_C.id
INNER JOIN table_D ON table_D.c_id == table_C.id
WHERE table_D.id == (the one inserted)
```

Here something I tried but didn't work :

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from typing import Optional

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    b_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('b.id'))
    b: Mapped['B'] = relationship(back_populates='aas')


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    aas: Mapped[List['A']] = relationship(back_populates='b')
    cs: Mapped[List['C']] = relationship(back_populates='b')

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    b_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('b.id'))
    b: Mapped['B'] = relationship(back_populates='cs')
    ds: Mapped[List['D']] = relationship(back_populates='c')

class D(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'd'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

    c_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('c.id'))
    c: Mapped['C'] = relationship(back_populates='ds')

    a_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('a.id'))
    a: Mapped['A'] = relationship(secondary='join(B,C,B.id==C.b_id)',
                                  secondaryjoin='A.b_id==B.id',
                                  primaryjoin='C.id==D.c_id',
                                    viewonly=True)

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session() as session:

    b1 = B()
    b2 = B()
    a1 = A(b=b1)
    a2 = A(b=b2)
    a3 = A(b=b1)
    c1 = C(b=b1)
    c2 = C(b=b2)
    d1 = D(c=c1, a=a1) # should work
    d2 = D(c=c2, a=a1) # shouldnt work because c2 linked to b2 linked to a2, not a1

    session.add_all([a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2])
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Specify `a_id` as a foreign key to table A.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the advice, I edited my post to be more precise about my issue, hope that helps you understand better

Comment: Not sure this makes sense because you cannot write to a view only relationship.  I think even if you were writing the id outside of the orm that this is a form a denormalization and you couldn't constrain it without using a trigger or something like that.  Why do you want this denormalized id, `D.a_id`?  You could just follow the relationship and get the same info right ?